# I've been an emailed a password; how can I proceed as securely as possible?

Tags: passwords, email, web-service

I am going through the on-boarding process for a summer internship with a well-known tech/bank company. I've received mail from HR requesting me to fill out an I-9 form via the external service they use.

I received, in two separate emails, a username and password (both in plain text, of course) for the service so that I can fill out the form.

I have already emailed my contact at HR informing them of the security issue. I do not believe anything will change in time for it to help me.

### TL;DR

I need to go through the (insecure) process. What steps can I take to minimize my risk?

Comment: Tagging on unfamiliar sites is remarkably difficult; I'll appreciate any help there.

Comment: Looks like all your can do is protect your email account.

Comment: can you change the password?

Comment: @schroeder i dont know; i havent tried logging in yet. Thats a good step (one i considered), changing it immediately on logging in

Comment: This really isn't a security flaw. Sure, they should use a one-time link, but it is still standard to use a one-time password that expires once you use it.

Comment: Try it out and if it doesn't expire once you use it, I'll re-open.

Comment: Also, most of the emails are encrypted in transit https://transparencyreport.google.com/safer-email/overview

Comment: @EsaJokinen is that specific to google? What if I’m using outlook, and I dont know what provider the sender used?

Comment: Have a look at the `Received` headers. They'll show whether TLS was used or not.